# Find the pdf of $Y$.

Tags: probability-theory

> The function $f$ is defined as $f(x) = cx^2,$ $0 ≤ x ≤ 1.$
>
> **(a)** Determine the constant $c$ so that this becomes a pdf of a random variable $X$.
>
> **(b)** Find the cdf and compute $P(X > 0.5)$.
>
> **(c)** Let $Y = \sqrt{X}$ and find the pdf of $Y$.

Questions (a) and (b) were trivial. However I don't understand what $Y=\sqrt{X}$ intuitively means. Can someone help me understand (c)?

Comment: What are you stuck on? The RV $Y: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $Y(\omega)=\sqrt{X(\omega)}$ where we are given the RV $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and its pdf. Surely your book covers *functions of random variables*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a different, but similar example.

Say I have a random variable X, which gives the number on the uppermost face shown on a fair dice. Thus the sample space is $\Omega_1=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

The pdf of this is given by: $\mathbb{P}[X=k]=\frac{1}{6}$

Now let $Y=X^2$, which means that whatever value of X we get, we must square it. Thus in this case, the sample space is: $\Omega_2=\{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36\}$

Now if I want to find the pdf of Y, I can do this as follows:
$$\mathbb{P}[Y=y]=\mathbb{P}[X^2=y]=\mathbb{P}[X=\sqrt{y}]=\frac{1}{6}$$

A similar argument can be applied to your problem, but instead of $Y=X^2$ it is $Y=\sqrt{X}$

Note: for the case of continuous variables, one should use: $$\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[g(X)\leq y]$$
since the the probability at a point is $0$. This would be the CDF, all you have to do is then differentiate to get the PDF.

Comment: A Godlike explanation. Thank you buddy! I'll try this first before I accept the answer.

Comment: What is $g(X)?$ Is it $\sqrt{X}$ in my case?

Comment: yes exactly...and in my given example $Y=g(X)=X^2$

Comment: For my answer to apply, the function $g$ must be monotonic...since $X^2$ and $\sqrt{X}$ are monotonic on $x>0$, then both our examples can be worked out using the method given in my answer

Comment: My motivation for that was that since $x\in[0,1]$ and $Y=\sqrt{X}$ then it follows that $y\in[0,1].$ Is monotonic on $x > 0$ the only requirement and $x$ and $y$ don't need to be in the same interval?

Comment: They need not be on the same interval...in fact in my given example, $\Omega_1\neq \Omega_2$, which is the sample space.

Comment: Now I get that the CDF of $Y$ is 

$$F_Y(x) = P(Y\le y) = P(\sqrt{X} \le y) = P(X\le y^2) = \int_0^{y^2}3 x^2 dx = y^6.$$

So the PDF is the derivative, which is $f_Y(x) = 5y^6$. But the book says the answer is $f_Y(x)=5x^6.$

Comment: $F_Y(x)=P(Y\leq x)$

Comment: In your answer you wrote $P(Y\le y) = P(g(X)\le y),$ why do I need $x$ instead of $y$ now? Where in the problem does it state that I should use $F_Y(x)$ instead of $F_Y(y)$? In my book they have examples using the latter.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference whether you write $y$ or $x$ since they just represent numbers. However by definition $F_Y(x)=P(Y\leq x)$ and $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)$. Both will result in the same function, but being represented by different variables, one being $x$ and the other $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much mate, this helped me understand a lot. I can now take on all the similar problems in the book.